# Bounty started but not found

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

While performing some janitorial cleanup on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765415/mtasc-onenterframe-loop/4771694#4771694) (as it has been deleted and I think only 10K users can see it, [here is the link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4765415/353410)), I came through the following comment [from an infuriated user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575164/anonymous?tab=reputation):

`You never promised an example. You said "figure it out yourself". Look at my rep points- I gave them away to a meaningless question out of frustration. – Anonymous yesterday`

I found evidence (-300 rep points) in his rep history that he started a bounty on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120078/away3d-vs-sandy-3d-and-other-flash-3d-engines-for-mobile), but the bounty is not showing there, and I don't understand what is happening.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3120078/revisions

Comment: Ha! As he wrote _I gave them away_ I never thought he meant ... _I gave them away ... to me_ :) Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

The user awarded the bounty to his own answer, as evidenced by the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3120078/revisions) of the question. To prevent gaming of the bounty system (because it gives these questions extra notice), self-awards are not given the bounty.